# How Get Ascii Code in javascript from external hardware?

Tags: javascript, browser, hex, ascii, hardware

I have a self designed hardware it's something like this image

[image]

 that it's connected to PC by USB and there is some keys on that Hardware. the hardware will send ASCII code over the USB to computer when each of the keys are pressed.

I need to capture pressed keys by javascript. is it possible? if yes can you guide me how?

please note that this is a self designed Hardware and I can change ASCII to any other type like HEX.

thanks in advance for any clue.

Comment: if it is mounted as a keyboard you can wait for *window.keydown*

Answer (score -1):

how is the device connected to the computer over usb?

do you also have a self designed driver?
if yes, so write an interface in the driver to connect the driver with the javascript

depending on your connection method, you can at last use a tcp connection to forward the code in java, i think it should also work in javascript? it would maybe not be the best way, but at last one way.

but if youu share more spcific information about the connection and how the computer recives the data, other ones can maybe give you better ideas

Comment: it's connected by USB and I don't have self driver